# npm ERR I can't install npm m1 MacBook

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install, nvm

the code is here its for generate 10,000 NFT gethub link (https://github.com/codeSTACKr/video-source-code-create-nft-collection.git)

I installed NodeJs. on my m1 Mac and every time I try to install npm inside the VsCode I get this error  I'm new to programing idk how can fix it I've been struggling for 2 weeks now

video-source-code-create-nft-collection % npm install
npm WARN read-shrinkwrap This version of npm is compatible with lockfileVersion@1, but package-lock.json was generated for lockfileVersion@2. I'll try to do my best with it!

> canvas@2.8.0 install /Users/ahmed/video-source-code-create-nft-collection/node_modules/canvas
> node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build

node-pre-gyp ERR! install response status 404 Not Found on https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas/releases/download/v2.8.0/canvas-v2.8.0-node-v83-darwin-unknown-arm64.tar.gz
node-pre-gyp WARN Pre-built binaries not installable for canvas@2.8.0 and node@14.18.2 (node-v83 ABI, unknown) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp)
node-pre-gyp WARN Hit error response status 404 Not Found on https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas/releases/download/v2.8.0/canvas-v2.8.0-node-v83-darwin-unknown-arm64.tar.gz
Package pixman-1 was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `pixman-1.pc' to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable No package 'pixman-1' found gyp: Call to 'pkg-config pixman-1 --libs' returned exit status 1 while in binding.gyp. while trying to load binding.gyp gyp ERR! configure error  gyp ERR! stack Error:` gyp` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit (/opt/homebrew/Cellar/node@14/14.18.2/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:351:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:400:28)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:282:12)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 21.2.0
gyp ERR! command "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/node@14/14.18.2/bin/node" "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/node@14/14.18.2/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "configure" "--fallback-to-build" "--module=/Users/ahmed/video-source-code-create-nft-collection/node_modules/canvas/build/Release/canvas.node" "--module_name=canvas" "--module_path=/Users/ahmed/video-source-code-create-nft-collection/node_modules/canvas/build/Release" "--napi_version=8" "--node_abi_napi=napi" "--napi_build_version=0" "--node_napi_label=node-v83"
gyp ERR! cwd /Users/ahmed/video-source-code-create-nft-collection/node_modules/canvas
gyp ERR! node -v v14.18.2
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v5.1.0
gyp ERR! not ok
node-pre-gyp ERR! build error
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute '/opt/homebrew/Cellar/node@14/14.18.2/bin/node /opt/homebrew/Cellar/node@14/14.18.2/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --module=/Users/ahmed/video-source-code-create-nft-collection/node_modules/canvas/build/Release/canvas.node --module_name=canvas --module_path=/Users/ahmed/video-source-code-create-nft-collection/node_modules/canvas/build/Release --napi_version=8 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=0 --node_napi_label=node-v83' (1)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess. (/Users/ahmed/video-source-code-create-nft-collection/node_modules/@mapbox/node-pre-gyp/lib/util/compile.js:89:23)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:400:28)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1058:16)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:293:5)
node-pre-gyp ERR! System Darwin 21.2.0
node-pre-gyp ERR! command "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/node@14/14.18.2/bin/node" "/Users/ahmed/video-source-code-create-nft-collection/node_modules/.bin/node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build"
node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd /Users/ahmed/video-source-code-create-nft-collection/node_modules/canvas
node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v14.18.2
node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v1.0.6
node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok
ahmed@Ahmeds-MacBook-Pro video-source-code-create-nft-collection % npm install
npm WARN read-shrinkwrap This version of npm is compatible with lockfileVersion@1, but package-lock.json was generated for lockfileVersion@2. I'll try to do my best with it!

> canvas@2.8.0 install /Users/ahmed/video-source-code-create-nft-collection/node_modules/canvas
> node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build

node-pre-gyp ERR! install response status 404 Not Found on https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas/releases/download/v2.8.0/canvas-v2.8.0-node-v83-darwin-unknown-arm64.tar.gz
node-pre-gyp WARN Pre-built binaries not installable for canvas@2.8.0 and node@14.18.2 (node-v83 ABI, unknown) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp)
node-pre-gyp WARN Hit error response status 404 Not Found on https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas/releases/download/v2.8.0/canvas-v2.8.0-node-v83-darwin-unknown-arm64.tar.gz
Package pixman-1 was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `pixman-1.pc' to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable No package 'pixman-1' found gyp: Call to 'pkg-config pixman-1 --libs' returned exit status 1 while in binding.gyp. while trying to load binding.gyp gyp ERR! configure error  gyp ERR! stack Error:` gyp` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit (/opt/homebrew/Cellar/node@14/14.18.2/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:351:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:400:28)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:282:12)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 21.2.0
gyp ERR! command "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/node@14/14.18.2/bin/node" "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/node@14/14.18.2/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "configure" "--fallback-to-build" "--module=/Users/ahmed/video-source-code-create-nft-collection/node_modules/canvas/build/Release/canvas.node" "--module_name=canvas" "--module_path=/Users/ahmed/video-source-code-create-nft-collection/node_modules/canvas/build/Release" "--napi_version=8" "--node_abi_napi=napi" "--napi_build_version=0" "--node_napi_label=node-v83"
gyp ERR! cwd /Users/ahmed/video-source-code-create-nft-collection/node_modules/canvas
gyp ERR! node -v v14.18.2
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v5.1.0
gyp ERR! not ok
node-pre-gyp ERR! build error
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute '/opt/homebrew/Cellar/node@14/14.18.2/bin/node /opt/homebrew/Cellar/node@14/14.18.2/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --module=/Users/ahmed/video-source-code-create-nft-collection/node_modules/canvas/build/Release/canvas.node --module_name=canvas --module_path=/Users/ahmed/video-source-code-create-nft-collection/node_modules/canvas/build/Release --napi_version=8 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=0 --node_napi_label=node-v83' (1)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess. (/Users/ahmed/video-source-code-create-nft-collection/node_modules/@mapbox/node-pre-gyp/lib/util/compile.js:89:23)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:400:28)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1058:16)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:293:5)
node-pre-gyp ERR! System Darwin 21.2.0
node-pre-gyp ERR! command "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/node@14/14.18.2/bin/node" "/Users/ahmed/video-source-code-create-nft-collection/node_modules/.bin/node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build"
node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd /Users/ahmed/video-source-code-create-nft-collection/node_modules/canvas
node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v14.18.2
node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v1.0.6
node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok
Failed to execute '/opt/homebrew/Cellar/node@14/14.18.2/bin/node /opt/homebrew/Cellar/node@14/14.18.2/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --module=/Users/ahmed/video-source-code-create-nft-collection/node_modules/canvas/build/Release/canvas.node --module_name=canvas --module_path=/Users/ahmed/video-source-code-create-nft-collection/node_modules/canvas/build/Release --napi_version=8 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=0 --node_napi_label=node-v83' (1)
npm WARN hashlips_art_engine@1.1.1 No repository field.

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! canvas@2.8.0 install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the canvas@2.8.0 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/ahmed/.npm/_logs/2021-12-14T00_37_55_725Z-debug.log

Comment: Did you try npm audit fix?

Comment: When you are in Your vscode terminal, what exactly are you typing that then receives error?

Comment: Try npm uninstall lockversion, then try npm install lockversion@1

Comment: I type (npm install)....   also I tried (npm i)and I got this new error(npm WARN hashlips_art_engine@1.1.1 No repository field.

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! canvas@2.8.0 install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the canvas@2.8.0 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/ahmed/.npm/_logs/2021-12-14T00_54_48_933Z-debug.log)

Comment: I tried npm install lockversion@1 and I got this error (npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/lockversion - Not found
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404  'lockversion@1' is not in the npm registry.
npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it (or use the name yourself!)
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/ahmed/.npm/_logs/2021-12-14T00_57_27_578Z-debug.log)

Comment: this is what I get when I try to use npm audit fix (
ahmed@Ahmeds-MacBook-Pro ~ % npm audit fix
npm ERR! code EAUDITNOPJSON
npm ERR! audit No package.json found: Cannot audit a project without a package.json

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/ahmed/.npm/_logs/2021-12-14T00_58_57_374Z-debug.log)

Comment: Try a fresh project and do npm init and keep hitting enter until you successfully create a package.json. Next try your npm install of whatever package you are needing. You usually always need a package.json THEN you run your npm installs of your packages and that creates a package.lock.json.

Comment: You should watch coding garden and coding train channels on youtube, they are really good coding teachers and specialize in all things javascript. Keep coding you will be a master in no time

Comment: Also, once you install nodejs, you dont need to manually add it to every vscode project. You just open your terminal, type npm init, push enter a bunch of times, sometimes you get asked wether to type y or n for yes or no to create the package.json. Once that is created it basically stores your versions of packages and start scripts for your app.

Comment: until right now it didn't works for me lol but I really appreciate your help and I will consider your advice thank you so much :)

Answer (score -1):

before install npm in vs code try:

```
nvm install
```

then

```
npm install
```

and try change node ver 14 before all of this